# How to safely view large kill-ring?

Tags: emacs

Last night, I wanted to grab an item from my kill ring -- or one that I was pretty sure was there. Rather than rotating through the kill-ring with `C-y` and multiple `M-y`, I decided to view the value of the variable with `C-h v` (describe variable) and typed `kill-ring`.

I'm not sure what was in my kill-ring, but this action pegged the resources of my decently powered MacBook Pro and I ended up killing emacs to get the computer operable again.

This raises a few questions:

1. Is there a safer way to view a kill-ring that is very large?
2. What's going on in Emacs that this would cause broader issues outside of Emacs itself?

(I'm using GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.35) - downloaded from http://emacsformacosx.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a [browse-kill-ring](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseKillRing) package.

Put into your .emacs

```
(require 'browse-kill-ring)
(browse-kill-ring-default-keybindings)
```

and you will be able to browse the kill ring by typing `M-y` without first using `C-y`.

Answer (score 2):

Excuse the shameless plug, but [here's my personal solution](http://nschum.de/src/emacs/kill-ring-search/) for that very problem: Incrementally searching the kill-ring.

[image]

Comment: Ooooo, that looks interesting. I'll have to try that.
Do you do anything special to handle unreasonably large items in the kill-ring?

Comment: It just searches for the next match and only has to display one at a time. That's simply a lot less work than printing the entire kill ring. It takes a few seconds to display a multi-megabyte match, but not minutes like C-h v.